# Check that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x^2)x^n$ uniformly converges on $[0;1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I was asked to check if the series of function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x^2)x^n$ uniformly convergences on $[0;1]$ or not.

This is my first try:

First, I find the partial sum:
$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-x^2)x^k=(1-x^2)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x=0 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x=1 \\ 
(1-x^2)\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} & \text{ if } 0<x<1
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x=0 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x=1 \\ 
(1+x)(1-x^n) & \text{ if } 0<x<1
\end{cases},$

we see that:

For $x=0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: S_n(0)=1$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1=1 .$

For $x=1$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:S_n(1)=0$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n(1)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}0=0 .$

For $0<x<1, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}: S_n(x)=(1+x)(1-x^n)$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+x)(1-x^n)=1+x.$

Thus, $S_n(x)$ converges pointwise to the function $S(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x=0 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x=1\\
1+x & \text{ if } 0<x<1
\end{cases}
$ on $[0;1]$.

Now, we check if $S_n(x)$ uniformly converges to $S(x)$ on $[0;1]$. We have:
$|S_n(x)-S(x)|=\begin{cases}
|1-1| & \text{ if } x=0 \\ 
|0-0| & \text{ if } x=1\\
|(1+x)(1-x^n)-(1+x)| & \text{ if } 0<x<1
\end{cases}
$
$=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x=0\\
0 & \text{ if } x=1\\ 
(1+x)x^n & \text{ if } 0<x<1
\end{cases}
$.

Thus, $\underset{x\in[0;1]}{sup}|S_n(x)-S(x)|=sup\left\{\underset{x\in(0;1)}{sup}[(1+x)x^n]; 0\right\}=sup\{2;0\}=2$. $\left(\underset{x\in(0;1)}{sup}(1+x)x^n=2 \: \text{since the function}\: g(x)=(1+x)x^n \: \text{is monotonically increasing on}\: (0;1),\:\text{so} (1+x)x^n<g(1)=2. \right)$

We see that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\underset{x\in[0;1]}{sup}|S_n(x)-S(x)|=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}2=2\neq 0,$ so $S_n(x)$ does not uniformly converge on $[0;1]$. And, so the given series of function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x^2)x^n$ does not uniformly convergences on $[0;1]$.

Is there any problems with my solution? Please, let me know where I should fix and modify!

It looks like I can't use the M-test in this case, so  is there any other simpler ways to solve this problem! It's nice to see your recommendations! Thanks!

Comment: Its much simpler. Each $S_n(x)$ is continuous but $S(x)$ is not so the convergence cannot be uniform

Comment: Note $S_n(0)=1\neq 0$

Comment: @athalhaids Yes, it's a simpler way! I forgot about that, thanks! But if it is required to use the definition, then my way is ok?

Comment: @BrianMoehring hmm, how 1? I mean $S_n(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-0^2)0^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}0=0+0+\cdots +0=0$, right?

Comment: If you want to interpret it that way, we must define $0^0=1\neq 0$.  On a more basic level, $x^0=1$ and no matter what which $x$-value we evaluate at, the constant function $1$ is still $1$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yeah, You're right, how silly I was! I made a mistake here! In this content (evaluating polynomials and power series), we define $0^0=1$! So $S_n(0)=1$, this also makes more sense to me in explaining why $S_n(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0;1]$! Thanks, I get it know!